# Distinct values from multiple tables from two different server in sql server

Tags: sql-server

I have multiple tables in two different server. The requirement is to fetch distinct vehicle dealer name from different zones. Ten zones are grouped in single server and other 15 zones in other server.
I used UNION ALL since I read it retrieves unique value. But it displayed the dealer name twice since two servers has the same dealer name.

[Server 1] 
ABC Co (in California zone)

[Server 2]
ABC Co (in Newyork zone)

But I want to display only one value as ABC Co despite of its zone. Any help much appreciated?

Comment: Important question: What if you have two "Joe's Autos" in two different regions that are actually different companies. Still only one listing?  In any case, the simplest way to do this is to create a view on both servers that gives you the distinct dealer names, link the servers, then query the views on each server in a UNION query.

Comment: ya I want it to be listed as one. Thank you

Answer (score 1):

Put a DISTINCT (or aggregation) query around your unions

```
SELECT DISTINCT * FROM 
(
    --your original query goes here
    SELECT * FROM Server1
    UNION ALL
    SELECT * FROM Server2
) A
```

- or -

```
SELECT CompanyName, Count(ZoneName) AS RepeatCount
FROM
(
    --your original query goes here
    SELECT CompanyName, ZoneName, etc FROM Server1
    UNION ALL
    SELECT CompanyName, ZoneName, etc FROM Server2
) A
GROUP BY CompanyName
```